# Multiple UISwitch states not saved to NSUserDefaults from modal screen

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have a storyboard in my app with my `UISwitch` element (checklist) and I am attempting to store the switch states so that if the user checks a few items and then leaves the page (modally) or closes the app with the Home key, the state of the `UISwitch` elements is remembered and the user can continue along with the checklist.

If an item is read and you turn the `UISwitch` off, the font turns red else the `UISwitch` is on and the font is White.

Everything seems to work (still learning OOP and Xcode 5) except if I back out of the page (leave modally) and then return the `UISwitch` elements are all On again. If I stop the simulator (or IPAD) and restart the app when I get to the page all `UISwitch` are ON again instead of what was selected being OFF.

If I use the Home button and return to the app the `UISwitch` elements are still in the state they were left.

In the .m file here is the `viewDidLoad` method for just one of the switches:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.SwitchFlipChart.on = ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"Switch1"] isEqualToString:@"On"]) ? (YES) : (NO);
}
```

and below is the `IBAction` method for the same `UISwitch` element

```
- (IBAction)SwitchFlipchart:(UISwitch *)sender{

if (SwitchFlipchart.on) {

LabelFlipchart.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

} else {

LabelFlipchart.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
SwitchFlipchart.hidden = YES;


NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (sender.tag == 0) {
if (sender.on == 0) {
[standardDefaults setObject:@"Off" forKey:@"Switch1"];
} else if (sender.on == 1) {
[standardDefaults setObject:@"On" forKey:@"Switch1"];  //removed f from fSwitch1
}
}

[standardDefaults synchronize];

}
```

Does it appear I am using the `NSUserDefaults` correctly or is it because I am reloading the page when stopping the Simulator or leaving the Page Modally?

Is there a better (sometimes easier is not better) way to work with `NSUserDefaults` and multiple `UISwitch` elements?

Is there a better way to retain `UISwitch` element state when loading a page after leaving it modally?

Is there  a better way to store `UISwitch` states than the `NSUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
- (IBAction)SwitchFlipchart:(UISwitch *)sender{

if (SwitchFlipchart.on) {

    LabelFlipchart.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

} else {

    LabelFlipchart.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
SwitchFlipchart.hidden = YES;


NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (sender.tag == 0) {
    if (sender.on == 0) {
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"Off" forKey:@"Switch1"];
    } else if (sender.on == 1) {
        [standardDefaults setObject:@"On" forKey:@"Switch1"];
    }
}

 [standardDefaults synchronize];

}
```

Explantion :-
You are setting on for wrong key. The key should be same Switch1 for both condition. But you are using fSwitch1 for On state. Please check your code.

Comment: Ithe code that I posted above does have that 1 error in it but the error does not exist in the code in my app. I did not cut and paste the code so I missesd that when entering on here.!

Comment: That does not fix the issue of the selected switches changing back to their default states when the app is closed ( not to the back ground and or you leave the page modally and then return to the page. When you leave and return all of the switches return to their default (ON ) states instead of maintaining their positions.

Comment: @yser3562325 ok send me your code I'll fix that. here is my mail address rahul.vyas.09@gmail.com

Comment: Rahul.Thank you for being willing to look at the code and I will post back here what you find so that hopefully this will get someone else the answer they need. I am a firm believer in passing on what we know to help someone else. thank you again!!